# How can I open multiple x window in linux and monitor each through x client?

Tags: xserver

I have to write a shell script to open about 10 x window, and start firefox in each window. And after the shell script run, our customer need to monitor the screen through remote client. Since each window is independent from each other, each customer only can see one x window screen belonged him through his x client. How can I do for this requirement ? Thanks

Comment: Anybody knows that please help me, many many thanks